# Running TensorFlow with XLA tf.function throws error

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-xla

When I'm trying to compile this [code](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/tutorials/jit_compile), getting the below error.

```
File "xla_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    @tf.function(jit_compile=True)
TypeError: function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jit_compile'
```

Answer (score 2):

Without switching to tf-nightly just use:

```
@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)
```

From the [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function#args_1):

> experimental_compile  If True, the function is always compiled by XLA. XLA may be more efficient in some cases (e.g. TPU, XLA_GPU, dense tensor computations).

In my case MCMC sampling took without that parameter: ~1 min 37 sec, with experimental_compile=True: ~6 sec.
Tensorflow built from sources (r2.4 branch).

Answer (score 0):

Installing tf-nightly resolved this issue.

```
pip install tf-nightly
```